# Why server detect application as robot, Instead of android version?

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am trying to build an application using retrofit 2.0 and OkHTTP library.Now the problem is when I hit the server from mobile browser,it detect my phone with android version. But when I hit the server via my application, the server detect it as robot.So what to do in my application for detecting my phone, because in future server will restrict robot type access.

Comment: show us your code, especially the one that use retrofit

Comment: I'm doing-

`OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

        httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {

            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

                Request original = chain.request();
                Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                        .header("User-Agent", "user-agent");
                Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });`

Comment: And then- 

        `Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(
                        GsonConverterFactory.create());
        Retrofit retrofit =
                builder.client(httpClient.build())
                        .build();
        loginAPI = retrofit.create(LoginAPI.class);`

Comment: @faruk can you help me in this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you can use `user-agent` header

You can inject custom header as default header for all http request, by inserting custom `OkHttpClient` in the retrofit object.

For example the custom header that you want to add is :

```
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'
```

Then your retrofit code should be like this :

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request original = chain.request();

            // Request customization: add request headers
            Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                    .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"); // <-- this is the important line

            Request request = requestBuilder.build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
});
OkHttpClient mClient = httpClient.build();

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
        .create();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(YOUR_BASE_URL)
        .client(mClient)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build();
```

Comment: Thank you so much.Woks fine :)

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely being caused by the User-Agent header or a mix of some additional headers. A more complex case could be if the server is checking if the client runs javascript this could be more complex. Try logging the headers you are sending.

```
Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpClient.class);
HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor =
    new HttpLoggingInterceptor((msg) -> {
        log.debug(msg);
});
loggingInterceptor.setLevel(Level.BODY);

// pass this client into Retrofit
OkHttpClient networkInterceptorClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addNetworkInterceptor(HttpClient.getLoggingInterceptor())
    .build();
```

This should give you very [detailed OkHttp logging](https://www.stubbornjava.com/posts/okhttpclient-logging-configuration-with-interceptors) including all the headers being sent. You can then add an interceptor to override the user agent on every HTTP request and pick a browser based one to make the server think you are using a web browser.

If this does not work continue comparing different headers and see if you can create a request with `cURL` that is not detected as a robot.